# Alamofire is not working

Tags: alamofire

I'm trying to install Alamofire onto my app, and I created a test app just in case, and no matter how many times I try and do it, it fails because there are like 250 errors all in the Alamofire section:

[image: error]

I've no idea what to do, I am stuck. I am still relatively new to coding, so I am not sure what to do here, but I was also wondering if there is a better thing to do rather then using Alamofire, because I have tried over 20 different apps to try and download Alamofire and they all have the same problem, as is seen above.

Comment: What is your Alamofire version? Xcode version?

Comment: Are you using pods for Alamofire? If yes then your pods are not installed properly. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by different swift versions vs different alamofire versions. For Swift 3 you need [AlamoFire 4.3](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)..
Also, try building your project with alamofire imported.

If that doesn't work and you're using CocoaPods then navigate to your app folder via terminal (`cd /path/to/app`) then do `pod reinstall` - make sure you have a podfile.